# Suppress popup for One2many form field

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

In Odoo 12, I've defined a form containing a One2many field.

```
<field name="child_ids">
  <tree>
     <field name="child_attr"/>
  </tree>
</field>
```

In both models (parent and child), all fields are defined as `readonly=True`. Clicking on a line of `child_ids`'s list yields a popup, **a behavior I'd like to suppress**.

So far I have tried, in all possible combinations, to no avail:

- adding `create="false" edit="false" editable="bottom"` to the `<tree>` tag (and some variations)
- adding `options="{'no_create': True, 'no_open': True}"` to the `<field>` tag
- creating an extra `ir.actions.act_window` for `child_ids`'s model that includes only `tree` as `view_mode`
- creating an empty form definition for `child_ids`'s model (this opens an empty popup)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I guess You have only created the tree view means form view used is default view meaning  options="{'no_open': True}" is not for the form view 
make form view also and add  options="{'no_open': True}" as you yourself suggested and it should work

Comment: sorry to confirm, but it's not working in Odoo v16 Community that I've just tried locally

Answer (score 0):

You can put `style="pointer-events:none;"` into the field's attribute and it would render the field uneditable and, at the same time, suppress the popup. For example,

```
<field name="child_ids" style="pointer-events:none;">
```

In case of inheriting from another view, use xpath like this.

```
<xpath expr="//path/to/the/field" position="attributes">
  <attribute name="style">pointer-events:none;</attribute>
</xpath>
```